# How to automatically delete document in MongoDB using Mongoose on some date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to create a document which automatically gets deleted on specific time using mongoose in NodeJS.

Writing this as a new question since I can find only TTL based solutions, I need expiry time based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB supports auto deleting documents. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/

In order to use this in Mongoose you need to create an index on the collection using this syntax:
`MySchema.index( { "expireAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 0 } );`

You also need to create a field in schema named `expireAt` and add the time at which you want the document to expire while adding document in the collection.

Comment: I want to delete Particular record in specific  time any idea about this ??
Every record delete time is different

Comment: After creating the above index just add a field named as expireAt in the record that you want to delete and set value of expireAt as the time at which you want to delete the record. Ex { name: a, expireAt: <time of deletion of a> }, { name: b, expireAt: <time of deletion of b> }